# Calculate combinations of certain characters while fixing some other characters on a certain spot

Tags: combinations, permutation, combinatorics

While doing some `cryptanalysis`, I come across a situation where I need to generate combinations of certain characters. This can be done easily using many online combination generators, except that I want to  **FIX**  the spot of certain characters that I already know are on the right spot while generating combinations for the rest. For example, I have the characters `'A', 'B', 'c', 'D, 'e', 'F', and 'g'`.

Now, I know that `'A'` would at the first spot. So fix `'A'` at first spot. Now, I know for second and third spot it could be `'B'` or `'c'`. So, permute `'B'` and `'c'` for second and third spot. For fourth spot, I have a fixed `'D'`. For fifth, a fixed `'e'`. For sixth, either `'F'` or `'f'`. For seventh, either `'g'` or `'3'`. and so on..

My question is how could I fix certain characters while permuting the rest in the way I want?  Is there any tool I could use or would I need to write my own? Could someone point me to an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with Python's `itertools.product()` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import product


def main():
    for characters in product(*['A', 'Bc', 'Bc', 'D', 'e', 'Ff', 'g3']):
        print(''.join(characters))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of that:

```
ABBDeFg
ABBDeF3
ABBDefg
ABBDef3
ABcDeFg
ABcDeF3
ABcDefg
ABcDef3
AcBDeFg
AcBDeF3
AcBDefg
AcBDef3
AccDeFg
AccDeF3
AccDefg
AccDef3
```

Comment: Ahh, just what I wanted. I love Python, and StackOverflow. Something new to learn every time I post here. A question: If I wanted the last character to be either a '!' or nothing -- e.g. either abcdefg! or abcdefg -- then I would write: `for characters in product(*['A', 'Bc', 'Bc', 'D', 'e', 'Ff', 'g3', '!\0'])`. Is that correct?

Comment: @intellikid No that would be either the '!' or a null byte in the last position.  The null byte is not seen when printing, but it is there and might confuse the program you use to process the output.  You could use `['!', '']` instead of `'!\0'`.  That's either '!' or an empty string.